# Book which mixes a story about a young girl at birthdays and helpful ideas for planning birthdays

Tags: identification-request

When I was younger my mum gave me a children’s book about birthdays. I've tried searching for the specifics I remember but no luck yet, hoping someone can help. I think it was published in the 80’s and given to me late 80’s early 90’s. It's a mix of a story of a young girl planning and attending birthday celebrations, and helpful ideas for planning birthdays. Aimed for ages 5+. Here are the pages I remember:

- Birthday party for twins.
- Make your own wrapping paper using potato stencil.
- Make your own decorations, paper rings, paper snowflakes.
- How to make a flower posy.
- Astrological birthstone and flower wheels.
- Face paint and fancy dress pictures.
- Daddy's home.
- Birthday poem.

I brought it to hospital when my mum was there for her to read and try to remember, but ended up losing the book when she moved to home. It's a British hardback A4 book with amazing illustrations.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It can be helpful to know when and where you had this book, when and in what language it was likely to have been published, and what sort of age range it was intended for. (A British 1970s book for teenagers? An Italian 2000s book for 5-year-olds? These would be very different search spaces.)

Comment: Thank you for helping my search. It was a British book, likely published late 80’s. I was given this book in the late 80’s / early 90’s. It was intended for children I imagine 5+

Comment: @KateHowe could you please [edit] your question to include these details?

Answer (score 3):

*Happy Birthday!* by Elizabeth Laird and Satomi Ichikawa could be a possibility.

[Goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5800851-happy-birthday)'s description:

> Follows a year of different birthday celebrations in a little girl's
> life and describes how birthdays are celebrated around the world.

I found few inside pictures on [this ebay listing](https://www.ebay.com/itm/HAPPY-BIRTHDAY-By-Satomi-Ichikawa-Elizabeth-Laird-Hardcover/115847181483).
*A midsummer birthday for the twins*, *Pretty paper*, *Dainty decorations*, *Delightful disguises*, *Funny faces*, *An autumn birthday for daddy*, *Birthstones and flowers* are some of the chapters.

Comment: Yes yes yes! This is it! Thank you for your help and so wonderful to see the front cover again! This has made my year, thank you all for your help

Comment: @KateHowe Please click the checkmark on the left of this answer to mark it as correct - that also marks the question as solved and gives a little extra thank-you to the answerer.